# Which version of Haiku do I need to run Gnash?

Tags: haiku

I'm confused by the gcc2/gcc4 and hybrid thing again.  Which nightly would I download before installing all the packages required by Gnash if I wanted to use dabbleboard.com or YouTube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work with the Alpha-2 and any recent hybrid-2 and hybrid-4 builds.